# Is there a way to get the ${DEVICE_STATE(SIP/${EXTEN})} output on asterisk AMI before making originate call

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I want to create e outbound dialer which will check if a user is available to take call or not before initiating a call from the extension

Answer (score 1):

Send this:

```
Action: Getvar
ActionID: 1
Variable: DEVICE_STATE(SIP/1107)
```

To get this:

```
Response: Success
ActionID: 1
Variable: DEVICE_STATE(SIP/1107)
Value: BUSY
```

It also works with PJSIP

Answer (score 0):

Yes Definitely. I use it a lot.

Action: SIPshowpeer

Description: Show one SIP peer with details on current status.

**Syntax:**

```
Action: SIPshowpeer
ActionID: <value>
Peer: <value>
```

Here is the wiki [link](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/ManagerAction_SIPshowpeer).

Comment: in SIPshowpeer I cant find anything in the response which tells me if the device is busy, unavaiable or not_inuse

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach:

```
Action: ExtensionState
Parameters: Exten, Context, ActionID
```

Take a little reading: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+ExtensionState

Answer (score 0):

You can add that peer into some asterisk queue.
After that you can use 'queue show [queueNumber]'
(visit https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/asterisk+cli+command+queue+show)
to get each peer status before initiating a call